# How can I use the remove method?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

In my backbone function, how can i remove the elements before i append new elements?, my function all works fine. the issue is while i click on the 'update' like, it's updating the elements and still the older version available. how can i remove the older elements, and append new from update call..?

**what is the correct way to clear the existing view elements and append new collections?**

my function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var school = {};

    school.model = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            name:'no name',
            age:'no age'
        }
    });

    school.collect = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:school.model,
        url:'js/school.json'
    });

    school.view = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName:'div',
        className:'member',
        template:$('#newTemp').html(),
        render:function(){
            var temp = _.template(this.template);
            this.$el.html(temp(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    school.views = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:$('#content'),
        events:{
            'click #newData' : 'newArrival',    
        },
        initialize:function(){
            _.bindAll(this);
            this.collection = new school.collect;
            this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
            this.collection.fetch();
        },
        newArrival:function(){
            school.views.remove(); // i tried this, throw the error 
            this.initialize();
        },
            render:function(){
                var that = this;
                _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
                    that.renderItem(item);    
                })
            },
            renderItem:function(item){
                //how can i remove the older elements and append new alone?
                var newItem = new school.view({model:item});
                this.$el.append(newItem.render().el); // keep adding but previous element still not removed, 
            }
        });

        var newSchool = new school.views;

})
```

Comment: i tried with this way, this is correct approach? my newArraival function added the line .. this.$el.find('div').remove(); it woks!

Comment: You should use backbones remove method (See my answer below). It will take care of destroying the view properly. this.$el.find('div').remove() is only using jquery to remove div-elements from the DOM (which will NOT remove backbone event listeners). I recommend a look at Backbone.Marionette, a backbone extension which solve many problems with event binding, collection views etc.

Comment: I update as like your suggestion, but still it is not removing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a reference to you old views to be able to remove them. You will then be able to to call remove on the child views. I highly recommend that you use backbones remove method instead of just removing elements from the DOM with jquery. Using Backbones remove will also unbind events from the object. To update from server, just call collection.fetch() to get new data. This is my solution (jsfiddle at the bottom):

```
var school = {};

school.model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        name:'no name',
        age:'no age'
    }
});

school.collect = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:school.model,
    url:'js/school.json'
});

school.view = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'div',
    className:'member',
    template:$('#newTemp').html(),
    render:function(){
        var temp = _.template(this.template);
        this.$el.html(temp(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});

school.views = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:$('#content'),
    events:{
        'click #newData' : 'newArrival',    
    },
    initialize:function(){
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.collection = new school.collect;
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
        this.collection.fetch();

        this.childViews = [];
    },
    newArrival:function(){
        this.collection.fetch();
    },
    render:function(){
        var that = this;

        // Remove old items
        _.each(this.childViews, function(old){
            old.remove();    
        });

        // Empty array of children
        this.childViews = [];

        var that = this;
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
            that.renderItem(item);    
        });
    },
    renderItem:function(item){
        //how can i remove the older elements and append new alone?
        var newItem = new school.view({model:item});
        this.$el.append(newItem.render().el); // keep adding but previous element still not removed, 

        // Store a reference to your child item.
        this.childViews.push(newItem);
    }
});

var newSchool = new school.views;
```

I have created a working: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EuCRZ/1/). Note: In the JSFiddle collection I override fetch() to provide fake data (You should remove that part).

Comment: I have updated the code, added a JSFiddle and did the update by collection.fetch();

Comment: It works. i just replaced removed the fetch function to work for my json data. thanks